# BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher fails to communicate with Samsung phone BLE beacon

Tags: c#, uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, windows-10-universal, samsung-mobile

I am developing a Windows 10 UWP app on Visual Studios 2017 Community.

I am attempting to read some information from android and IOS devices. I use a BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher watcher which looks for valid BLE advertisement packets that are in range. I than connect to the Gatt service with a specific service Uuid. Finally I read the characteristics attached to the service.

This works fine for all devices that I have tested so far except for two S7 Samsung phones.

The process does actually work, but it is very slow and eventually will stop working and even block the bluetooth stack. After a while I will have to manually turn the bluetooth off and on again.

I consistently get these errors after every BLE communication with a Samsung S7 phone:

> onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\common\devquerydevpropprovider.cpp(297)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!1462192B: (caller: 14621514) ReturnHr(15) tid(36d4) 80070490 Element not found.
>
> onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\common\devquerydevpropprovider.cpp(131)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!14621555: (caller: 14578E83) ReturnHr(16) tid(36d4) 80070490 Element not found.
>
> onecoreuap\drivers\wdm\bluetooth\user\winrt\device\bluetoothledevice.cpp(1418)\Windows.Devices.Bluetooth.dll!14578E9A: (caller: 14576350) LogHr(8) tid(36d4) 80070490 Element not found.

And here is the code that I use to connect to the Gatt service:

```
    private async void OnAdvertisementReceived(
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher sender,
        BluetoothLEAdvertisementReceivedEventArgs args)
    {
        BluetoothLEDevice bleModule = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);

        var gattServicesResult = await bleModule.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(new Guid("YYYYYYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYY-YYYYYYYYYYYY"));
        if (gattServicesResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
        {
            foreach (var gattService in gattServicesResult.Services.ToList())
            {
                if (gattServicesResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    GattCharacteristicsResult characteristicsImageID = await gattService.GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync(new Guid("XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX"));
                    if (characteristicsImageID.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                    {
                        string imageID = null;
                        foreach (GattCharacteristic gattImageID in characteristicsImageID.Characteristics.ToList())
                        {
                            GattReadResult valueImageID = await gattImageID.ReadValueAsync();
                            IBuffer bufferImageID = valueImageID.Value;

                            DataReader dataReaderImageID = DataReader.FromBuffer(bufferImageID);

                            imageID = dataReaderImageID.ReadString(bufferImageID.Length);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The line that causes the errors (which aren't actually fatal) is:

```
    bleModule = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync(args.BluetoothAddress);
```

My question is, has anyone else found this to be a problem and whether or not there is a solution to it? (it may need Microsoft to fix a problem in their BLE implementation).

Comment: So it seems only Samsung S7 phone has this kind of problem. What's your SDK version and what's the device that you are using to read data from Samsung S7 phone?

Comment: I am using the Creators Update SDK such that I can connect to the Gatt service without specifically pairing with the device. All windows devices are affected (surface, pavillion laptop, linx tablet)